# I cannot get past an "unknown problem" error when trying to login to discussions.apple.com

Tags: apple-id, login, websites

I have noticed that when I try to post to any forum threads on https://discussions.apple.com it fails.

1. I type my `Apple ID` details at the login page.
2. Then I am prompted to reconfirm the details for security.
3. I am then told there has been an **unknown problem**.
4. I am given the option to manage my `Apple ID`.
5. When I click the button to do this, I am prompted to type in my login details.
6. After I do this I have to delete the email address that is in the box and retype it otherwise I will go back to the **unknown error**.

Once I am at the manage page and have logged in, I load a seperate tab and try to visit the threads I visited earlier but I am prompted again to enter my username and password - which I can not get passed.

I would have assumed that there was a possible malware issue on my Mac but the **same happens on both my iPad and iPhone**. Is there any known issues with either `Apple ID` or with there website?

Comment: Also i tried searching google and most of the pages pointed to apple support forums of which i can not access once this issue has happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are occasional timeouts when the service that validates an Apple ID and password combination fails to report back to the web server running any of Apple's services (like the discussions, stores, review process, bug reporter, etc...)

If this error persists over a day or more and there isn't a [public outage](http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/), you will need to contact support for [help with your Apple ID](http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/).